# Segmentation fault C: malloc(sizeof(char*)*3)

Tags: c, multithreading

Problem:
pass struct with char *memoria to a thread
Segmentation fault

Code:
main.c

```
 memoria=malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
 ...
 parametri_thread_ram[0].memoria = (char*)memoria;
```

funzioni.h

```
struct thread_cpu {
int *i;
int *numCpu;
char *memoria;
};
```

cpu.c

```
   my_data = (struct thread_cpu*) thread_arg;
   memoria = (intptr_t)my_data -> memoria;
   ...
   memoria[0] = buffer[0]; //buffer[0]='W'
   sprintf(help,"%d",operandi[0]);
   memoria[1] = help; help='2'   <------------------segmentation fault
   sprintf(help,"%d",operandi[1]);
   memoria[2] = help; help='4'
```

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with the code in your question: `malloc(3*sizeof(char))` vs. `malloc(sizeof(char*)*3)`

Comment: You have a struct member named `memoria`. You must have a pointer variable named `memoria`, which you assign to in `main.c`. You must also have an integer variable named `memoria`, which you assign an `intptr_t` value to in `cpu.c`. But you haven't shown us those declarations. Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Should `memoria` be an array of three integer types or char types? From the usage it seems to be the former.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `help`? Where is the declaration of `memoria`? How can one even begin to answer this question without knowing what `help` is and what `memoria` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `memoria` declaration is of the wrong size; it should be:

```
memoria=malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
```

Otherwise it will be the size of three *pointers* to char (which is typically bigger).

Secondly, because you're using `sprintf()` you need `help` to be a char buffer that's big enough, e.g.:

```
char help[20];
```

Then, assuming you only want to store the first character inside `memoria`:

```
sprintf(help, ...)
memoria[1] = help[0];
sprintf(help, ...)
memoria[2] = help[0];
```

Btw, most of the above issues should have showed up during compilation (using `gcc -Wall`).

Comment: I need 3 char not 3 string

Comment: char help; help declaration

Comment: memoria=malloc(sizeof(char)*3);// nope :(

Comment: char help[10]; yessssss :)

Comment: @Jack: C doesn't have a "string type". `char help[10];` declares `help` as an array, which may *contain* a string.

Comment: @KeithThompson My mind translates "char*" into "string type" :) I'm aware of the difference, though.

Comment: @Jack: `help` isn't a `char*` either; it's a `char[10]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very cryptic. You really should have included complete code rather than have us try to reverse engineer your code. Anyway we have:

```
help='2';
```

Which means that `help` is of type `char`.

And we also have:

```
sprintf(help, "%d", operandi[0]);
```

This can only work if `help` points to a block of memory large enough to receive the string that you a generating. Clearly that is not the case.

The rest of your code looks very sketchy too. I cannot see why you would be allocating memory for 3 `char*` pointers. And I don't understand why you need to do all of this outside the type system. You would do well to attempt to remove as many casts as possible and let the compiler help you. The compiler is here to help and you are stopping it doing so with your casting.